# Which programming language gets the most questions and/or traffic on stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

I'm looking for some data other than http://langpop.com/ so it would be interesting if there was some charts for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

If you check out the [tag count](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) you can get a good idea of language popularity.

[C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are currently the most popular tags.

Comment: Adding to this, here's a breakdown of stats for C# vs Java http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/why-so-many-questions-tagged-c-on-stackoverflow/6903#6903

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework in general is the most popular topic on StackOverflow. The C# language is leaps and bounds more popular than Visual Basic.

After C#, Java development is the next most popular topic.